# Type of visa for the UK

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm a Tunisian citizen residing in France, I have a face to face meeting regarding a scientific project during the month of august. However I am lost to what type of visa I should be applying for.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use visa4uk and apply for a standard-visitor-visa.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016, the only UK visa for short-term business/tourist/scientific activities is the [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa). Apply for it through [Visa4Uk](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/).